# Calling another JSF component from within custom component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, custom-component

Is it possible to call another JSF component from within a custom component (as opposed to from a composite one)?

In particular, I'm looking to call the PrimeFaces message component from within another component's encodeEnd method

I was (naively) hoping for something like this:

```
@Override
public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component)
        throws java.io.IOException {

    // Do stuff...

    // set up Message object
    // tell Message object the current component's id
    // render Message object
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
import org.primefaces.component.message.Message;

// ...

Message message = new Message();
message.setParent(component);
message.setFor(component.getId());
message.encodeAll(context);
```

Comment: Ah, I was close. I missed out the message.setFor step and then was convinced I was doing the wrong thing entirely. However, a problem remains.

Now I get the error message, I also get the error message produced before the component itself, replicated by the number of times the form has been submitted!

Comment: Yes, that was what my original answer did. Have you checked the update which I made 14 minutes ago? Note that this is normally not entirely the right place to add children (and hence my original approach unexpectedly failed). You'd rather do the job during `postAddToView` event or so.

Comment: Just tried it.

Unfortunately I'm getting an error on the message.setParent(component) line

`WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$4.visit(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:331)`

postAddToView? Uhoh, getting further and further out my depth here...

Comment: Adding setParent to my search now brings up this post by PrimeFaces author Cagatay - http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2005/12/13/dynamically_adding_components_to_a/ which has basically the same ideas. message.setParent still blows me up though :(

Comment: What Mojarra version are you using? I tested on 2.1.9 and works just fine.

Comment: I'm running NetBeans 7.1.2 with GlassFish 3.1.2. Not sure how to work out which version of Mojarra that is...

Comment: If I'm not wrong, GF 3.1.2 bundles 2.1.6. Try updating it. Just replace the JAR in `/glassfish/modules` folder.

Comment: You're not wrong - that totally fixes it. You're a legend Balus!